# MATLAB's pcacov on numpy/scipy?

Tags: matlab, numpy, scipy

I was wondering what function in numpy/scipy corresponded to pcacov() in MATLAB. If there isn't a corresponding one, what would be the best way to implement the function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumPy and SciPy don't have specific routines for PCA, but they do have the linear algebra primitives required to compute it. Any pca function in any language will basically be just a light wrapper around an eigenvalue or singular value decomposition, with different conventions regarding centering, normalization, meaning of matrix dimensions, and terms (eigenvectors, principal components, principal vectors, latent variables, etc. are all different names for the same thing, sometimes with slight variations).

So, for example, given a matrix `X` you can compute the PCA using the SVD:

```
import numpy as np

def pca(X):
    X_centered = X - X.mean(0)
    u, s, vt = np.linalg.svd(X_centered)
    evals = s[::-1] ** 2 / (X.shape[0] - 1)
    evecs = vt[::-1].T
    return evals, evecs

np.random.seed(0)
X = np.random.rand(100, 3)
evals, evecs = pca(X)

print(evals)
# [ 0.06820946  0.08738236  0.09858988]

print(evecs)
# [[-0.49659797  0.4567562  -0.73808145]
#  [ 0.34847559  0.88371847  0.31242029]
#  [ 0.79495611 -0.10205609 -0.59802118]]
```

If you have a covariance matrix, you can compute the PCA using an eigenvalue decomposition:

```
def pcacov(C):
    return np.linalg.eigh(C)

C = np.cov(X.T)
evals, evecs = pcacov(C)

print(evals)
# [ 0.06820946  0.08738236  0.09858988]

print(evecs)
# [[-0.49659797 -0.4567562  -0.73808145]
#  [ 0.34847559 -0.88371847  0.31242029]
#  [ 0.79495611  0.10205609 -0.59802118]]
```

The results are the same, up to a sign in the eigenvector columns.

Now, I've used a particular set of conventions here regarding whether datapoints are in rows or columns, how the covariance is normalized, etc. and those details vary from implementation to implementation of PCA. So the Matlab code might give different results because it's using different conventions internally. But under the hood, it's doing something very similar to the computations used above.